# fixed header have a strange error - transparent text?

Tags: css

I have a fixed header and when i scroll the page, its like the text is transparent, but only in one section of the web.

Example :

```
http://198.199.80.178/anuncios/prueba-ultima
```

And move the scroll to the bottom and looks at the header.

I use the same css to other section of the web and it only happens in this section, in others does not happens.

Look at this example :

```
http://198.199.80.178/anuncios/buscar?utf8=✓&precio_min=0&precio_max=6000
```

if i scroll the web to the bottom, the header is always the same, in the other, in some moment, is like it would be transparent.

Any idea ?? I am totally out, i dont find why it happens.

Thanks in advance

Edit- Added an image with the differences

[image: screen shot]

Good - the white texts are not transparent.

Bad - Look at the text of the button and the rigth section, the white text "Registrarme". Its like the white color is transparent in both texts.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the issue on the site. Nothing happens to the header when I scroll on either page.

Comment: ok, but i dont know what paste. I only ask for a idea because i am totally lost. I can paste the html code, the javascript, the bootstrap css, the custom css.....but i dont know if the error is in body, in header, in the container.....for this reason i pasted the link and when i can determite the error, i would paste everything i can.

Comment: Look the white text on the header ( the green button and the rigth text ) and scroll the web to the bottom.

Comment: At the very least you should update you question with perhaps a screenshot or a better explanation of the problem.  I cant find any differences between the two pages you linked on any of the browsers I've tried.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i added 2 screenshots and i will made a collage joining the screenshots to view better the differences

Comment: Because it's easy for CSS to get in a tangle, try removing large chunks of the CSS and test. If you are still seeing the issue then put that chunk back in and remove another chunk. Keep going until you remove a chunk that fixes the problem... then you can fine tune to find exactly which declarations are causing the issue. If you can't find it by doing this then perhaps the issue is elsewhere. You should also test across many browsers because the header looks fine on my computer/browser combination. It might even be an anti-aliasing problem peculiar to your computer - I've seen that before.